# Can SurfaceTexture produce a stream of textures?

Tags: android

Am writing a custom video decoder based on `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec`.

The decoding video `MediaCodec` sends its output buffers to a `Surface` (producer) which belongs to a `SurfaceTexture` (consumer) which is notified that a new buffer is available via the `onFrameAvailable` callback. So far so good.

What I would like is to be able to take `SurfaceTexture`'s texture that holds the most recent video frame and dispatch that into my GL-based rendering system, and for the *next* frame to use a *new* texture. If this was possible I'd be able to render video frames very cheaply, i.e. without having to render/copy to an offscreen buffer first.

But I cannot get it to work. I've tried using `detachFromGLContext` and `releaseTexImage` and I end up with black frames or crashes. I'm pretty sure that if only a texture could be disconnected from `SurfaceTexture` without destroying it then it would work.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?